# Hosting for app with Python 2.7, Tornado, MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, hosting, tornado, web-hosting

I want to publish my web site. Source code is located on GitHub.
My tech: Python 2.7, Tornado, MongoDB, MongoEngine.

I am interested in free hosting. What should I use or should I do?
Thanks in advance.

PS OpenShift is working only with Django I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your application on Google App Engine (20 free instances). You can use a Tornado GAE Template (e.g https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos/appengine) to set up Python environment, and you can host Mongo on MLab.